# Is there a reason to keep HTTP/1.0 support on the web server?

Tags: iis, web-server, http

I'd like to **switch off the support for `HTTP/1.0`** on my web servers. These servers host regular websites (MVC.NET).

- What are the potential negative implications?
- Are there any important Internet services using `HTTP/1.0` which I should be aware of?

Answer (score 3):

HTTP/1.1 was introduced 20 years ago in January 1997. Every modern browser uses it, so disabling the support for HTTP/1.0 would not affect any actual user. Some web crawlers seems to claim they are using `HTTP/1.0`, but as these appears in the logs of virtual hosts (not supported in HTTP/1.0) too, I doubt that they should be fully capable of using HTTP/1.1.

For short explanation of the differences, see [RFC 2616 19.6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-19.6.1). If you want deeper understanding, read the [Key Differences between HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1](http://www8.org/w8-papers/5c-protocols/key/key.html).

Let's go back to one of the main differences, virtual hosts already mentioned in the first paragraph:

> For example, if a user makes a request for the resource at URL
> `http://example1.org/home.html`, the browser sends a message with the
> Request-Line
>
> ```
> GET /home.html HTTP/1.0
> ```
>
> to the server at `example1.org`. This prevents the binding of another HTTP server hostname, such as
> `exampleB.org` to the same IP address, because the server receiving such
> a message cannot tell which server the message is meant for. Thus, the
> proliferation of vanity URLs causes a proliferation of IP address
> allocations.
>
> The Internet Engineering Steering Group (IESG), which manages the IETF
> process, insisted that HTTP/1.1 take steps to improve conservation of
> IP addresses. Since HTTP/1.1 had to interoperate with HTTP/1.0, it
> could not change the format of the Request-Line to include the server
> hostname. Instead, HTTP/1.1 requires requests to include a `Host`
> header, first proposed by John Franks [Fra94], that carries the
> hostname. This converts the example above to:
>
> ```
> GET /home.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: example1.org
> ```
>
> If the URL references a port other than the default (TCP port 80),
> this is also given in the Host header.

Virtual hosts are nowadays so common that actually lack of them is extraordinary. See whether you get the same page with your domain name and with the IP address or not. If you don't, you already aren't fully supporting HTTP/1.0 in any practical manner; abandoning it wouldn't be a radical change.